# encode .wav file using ffmpeg in objective c or c

Tags: objective-c, c, ffmpeg, encode

I have to encode .wav file and write it into same file,or other file using

ffmpeg library,here is my code for encoding

```
-(void)audioencode:(const char *)fileName
{

    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket pkt;
    int i, j, k, ret, got_output;
    int buffer_size;
    FILE *f;
    uint16_t *samples;

    const char *format_name = "wav", 


const char *file_url = "/Users/xxxx/Downloads/simple-drum-beat.wav";

    avcodec_register_all();

    av_register_all();

    AVOutputFormat *format = NULL;

    for (AVOutputFormat *formatIter = av_oformat_next(NULL); formatIter != NULL; formatIter = av_oformat_next(formatIter) 
{
        int hasEncoder = NULL != avcodec_find_encoder(formatIter->audio_codec);
        if (0 == strcmp(format_name, formatIter->name)) {
            format = formatIter;
            break;
        }
    }


    AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(format->audio_codec);

    NSLog(@"tet test tststs");

    AVCodecContext *c;

        c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

        if (!c) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio codec context\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        c->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
        if (!check_sample_fmt(codec, c->sample_fmt)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Encoder does not support sample format %s",
                    av_get_sample_fmt_name(c->sample_fmt));
            exit(1);
        }
    c->bit_rate = 64000;//705600;
   c->sample_rate    = select_sample_rate(codec);
    c->channel_layout = select_channel_layout(codec);
    c->channels       = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(c->channel_layout);
    c->frame_size = av_get_audio_frame_duration(c, 16);

    int bits_per_sample = av_get_bits_per_sample(c->codec_id);


    int frameSize   = av_get_audio_frame_duration(c,16);

        /* open it */
        if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        f = fopen(fileName, "wb");
        if (!f) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", fileName);
            exit(1);
        }

        /* frame containing input raw audio */
        frame = av_frame_alloc();
        if (!frame) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        frame->nb_samples     = frameSize/*c->frame_size*/;
        frame->format         = c->sample_fmt;
        frame->channel_layout = c->channel_layout;

        buffer_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, c->channels,frameSize /*c->frame_size*/,
                                                 c->sample_fmt, 0);
        samples = av_malloc(buffer_size);
        if (!samples) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate %d bytes for samples buffer\n",
                    buffer_size);
            exit(1);
        }

        /* setup the data pointers in the AVFrame */
        ret = avcodec_fill_audio_frame(frame, c->channels, c->sample_fmt,
                                       (const uint8_t*)samples, buffer_size, 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not setup audio frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    float t, tincr;
        /* encode a single tone sound */
        t = 0;
        tincr = 2 * M_PI * 440.0 / c->sample_rate;
        for(i=0;i<800;i++) {
            av_init_packet(&pkt);
            pkt.data = NULL; // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
            pkt.size = 0;

            for (j = 0; j < frameSize/*c->frame_size*/; j++) {
                samples[2*j] = (int)(sin(t) * 10000);

                for (k = 1; k < c->channels; k++)
                    samples[2*j + k] = samples[2*j];
                t += tincr;
            }
            /* encode the samples */
            ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
            if (ret < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding audio frame\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            if (got_output) {
                fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, f);
                av_free_packet(&pkt);
            }
        }
}
```

but after encoded file size is zero,
Please suggest what m doing wrong,any help will be appreciate, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you call `fclose`? You need to properly close the file after you are done with writing to it.

Comment: yeah @SelçukCihan,m adding